# 'Unable to load manifest file' when running Portal 2

Tags: steam, pc, portal-2

I recently deleted and reinstalled Steam and my games because they weren't working properly. I just finished installing Portal 2, hit play, and it showed an error message:

> Unable to load manifest file ‘scripts/game_sounds_manifest.txt’

Does anyone know any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried verifying the game cache?

Comment: yes i have, multiple times sadly. it didn't work- the same thing happened.

Comment: Please try to find that file – it should be inside `SteamApps/common/Portal 2/portal2/scripts/`, delete it and verify the game files again. Steam should redownload it.

Comment: Hmm, try uninstalling steam, and then delete the the portal 2 game folder in C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Portal 2

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question in steam https://steamcommunity.com/app/570/discussions/0/846941710218354354/ the answer, was said to be working for some.